# Enabling SSL configuration issue

Tags: neo4j

I am having issues enabling SSL configuration.
I walked through the guide provided on docs and searched through the other peoples posts but still cannot make it work. Therefore I kindly ask for your help :)

I am using neo4j `4.1.0 Enterprise` on macOS Catalina ver. 10.15.5
When starting server I receive following error:

```
2020-07-06 16:54:16.837+0000 INFO  Starting...
2020-07-06 16:54:24.804+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.1.0 ========
2020-07-06 16:54:25.162+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j on dbms.connector.http.listen_address, a socket address. If missing port or hostname it is acquired from dbms.default_listen_address. Error starting Neo4j database server at /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-abc65513-dd91-4140-b69c-201fc2ec2aa8/installation-4.1.0/data/databases
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting Neo4j database server at /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-abc65513-dd91-4140-b69c-201fc2ec2aa8/installation-4.1.0/data/databases
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:198)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:158)
    at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseManagementServiceFactory.createManagementService(EnterpriseManagementServiceFactory.java:38)
    at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseBootstrapper.createNeo(EnterpriseBootstrapper.java:20)
    at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:117)
    at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:87)
    at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:25)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.bolt.BoltServer@29dcdd1c' failed to initialize. Please see the attached cause exception "io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLPrivateKeyMethod".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:424)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:101)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:189)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/internal/tcnative/SSLPrivateKeyMethod
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:471)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:571)
    at org.neo4j.ssl.SslPolicy.nettyServerContext(SslPolicy.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltServer.createSslContext(BoltServer.java:286)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltServer.createExternalProtocolInitializer(BoltServer.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltServer.init(BoltServer.java:154)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:403)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLPrivateKeyMethod
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 16 more
2020-07-06 16:54:25.162+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

Server fails to start when line `dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL` is uncommented.

If I am not mistaken it is related to `io/netty/internal/tcnative/SSLPrivateKeyMethod`
I spent much time trying to figure out what is the problem and I have no clue how to proceed anymore.

I generated self-signed certificate with command:

```
openssl req \
       -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout private.key \
       -x509 -days 365 -out public.crt
```

certificate folder structure is following

```
└── default
    ├── private.key
    ├── public.crt
    ├── revoked
    └── trusted
```

plugins are following:

```
netty-all-4.1.50.Final-sources.jar
netty-all-4.1.50.Final.jar
```

My configuration `neo4j.conf` is following:

```
#*****************************************************************
# Neo4j configuration
#
# For more details and a complete list of settings, please see
# https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/
#*****************************************************************

# This setting constrains all `LOAD CSV` import files to be under the `import` directory. Remove or comment it out to
# allow files to be loaded from anywhere in the filesystem; this introduces possible security problems. See the
# `LOAD CSV` section of the manual for details.
dbms.directories.import=import

# Whether requests to Neo4j are authenticated.
# To disable authentication, uncomment this line
dbms.security.auth_enabled=true


#********************************************************************
# Memory Settings
#********************************************************************

# Java Heap Size: by default the Java heap size is dynamically calculated based
# on available system resources. Uncomment these lines to set specific initial
# and maximum heap size.
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=1G

# The amount of memory to use for mapping the store files.
# The default page cache memory assumes the machine is dedicated to running
# Neo4j, and is heuristically set to 50% of RAM minus the Java heap size.
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=512m

# Transaction state location. It is recommended to use ON_HEAP.
dbms.tx_state.memory_allocation=ON_HEAP


#*****************************************************************
# Network connector configuration
#*****************************************************************

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
#dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687
#dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address=localhost:9000

# HTTP Connector. There can be zero or one HTTP connectors.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473


#*****************************************************************
# SSL policy configuration
#*****************************************************************

# Bolt SSL configuration
dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.base_directory=certificates/default
dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.private_key=private.key
dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.public_certificate=public.crt
dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.client_auth=NONE
dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.trust_all=true

# Https SSL configuration
dbms.ssl.policy.https.enabled=true
dbms.ssl.policy.https.base_directory=certificates/default
dbms.ssl.policy.https.private_key=private.key
dbms.ssl.policy.https.public_certificate=public.crt
dbms.ssl.policy.https.client_auth=NONE
dbms.ssl.policy.https.trust_all=true


#*****************************************************************
# Miscellaneous configuration
#*****************************************************************

# A comma separated list of procedures and user defined functions that are allowed
# full access to the database through unsupported/insecure internal APIs.
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*


#********************************************************************
# JVM Parameters
#********************************************************************

# G1GC generally strikes a good balance between throughput and tail
# latency, without too much tuning.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UseG1GC

# Have common exceptions keep producing stack traces, so they can be
# debugged regardless of how often logs are rotated.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

# Make sure that `initmemory` is not only allocated, but committed to
# the process, before starting the database. This reduces memory
# fragmentation, increasing the effectiveness of transparent huge
# pages. It also reduces the possibility of seeing performance drop
# due to heap-growing GC events, where a decrease in available page
# cache leads to an increase in mean IO response time.
# Try reducing the heap memory, if this flag degrades performance.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

# Trust that non-static final fields are really final.
# This allows more optimizations and improves overall performance.
# NOTE: Disable this if you use embedded mode, or have extensions or dependencies that may use reflection or
# serialization to change the value of final fields!
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields

# Disable explicit garbage collection, which is occasionally invoked by the JDK itself.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+DisableExplicitGC

#Increase maximum number of nested calls that are can be inlined from 9 (default) to 15
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:MaxInlineLevel=15

# Restrict size of cached JDK buffers to 256 KB
dbms.jvm.additional=-Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=262144

# More efficient buffer allocation in Netty by allowing direct no cleaner buffers.
dbms.jvm.additional=-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true

# Expand Diffie Hellman (DH) key size from default 1024 to 2048 for DH-RSA cipher suites used in server TLS handshakes.
# This is to protect the server from any potential passive eavesdropping.
dbms.jvm.additional=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048

# This mitigates a DDoS vector.
dbms.jvm.additional=-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true

# Increase the default flight recorder stack sampling depth from 64 to 256, to avoid truncating frames when profiling.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=256

# Allow profilers to sample between safepoints. Without this, sampling profilers may produce less accurate results.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+DebugNonSafepoints

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
dbms.windows_service_name=neo4j

#********************************************************************
# Other Neo4j system properties
#********************************************************************

dbms.netty.ssl.provider=OPENSSL
```

Does anyone have clue what is the reason for my issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was replacing

> netty-all-4.1.50.Final-sources.jar
> netty-all-4.1.50.Final.jar

with

`netty-tcnative-2.0.31.Final-osx-x86_64.jar`
`netty-tcnative-2.0.31.Final-sources.jar`

Answer (score 1):

The error log is saying that the class `SSLPrivateKeyMethod` is not found. The error is not related to the content of the certificate.

Check the classpath that Neo4j Server refers to. For example, check if `netty-all-4.1.50.Final.jar` contains the `SSLPrivateKeyMethod` class.